# MDIContainer Pass variable and One window

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, containers, mdi

i  
 Hallo,
 m using MDIContainer.
 1. How can i pass the varaible from parent to child ?
 2.How can i prohibited to open more than 1 window with the same Name (That means in my MenuStrip there are Ordre,Tarif,Config... when user already open the Ordre, when he click the menustrip ordre again, it not open a new window/created a new child but pointed to the ordre window that already open) ?

Thanx before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a private, protected or public member in your mdicontainer window:

```
class MyMdiContainer : Form
{
    private object m_var;

    // Property approach
    public object MyVar
    {
        get { return m_var; }
        set { m_var = value; }
    }
}
```

And here is the mdi child:

```
class MyMdiChild : Form
{
    private object m_childVar;

    void Communicate()
    {
        // Read variable
        this.m_childVar = ((MyMdiContainer) this.MDIParent).MyVar;

        ((MyMdiContainer) this.MDIParent).MyVar = "Child Foo";
    }
}
```

In the example above we use two fields, each one for the two classes, property for storing the var in the MDI parent, and method in child for making a communication on the variable and storing a copy inside the child.

This is useful for parent to child, but it should be implemented in different way for parent to many children with synchronization.

Comment: Thaks you for your response.
i use passing via constructor.
public Lordre()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
        }

        public Lordre(string ClientID)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lbl_Err.Text = "qdsf" + ClientID;
        }

<br>i wonder if there are a general variable in Program.cs. that meant Once i put it, i can retrive the value from any form.

Comment: You may create a static class for this purposes, instead of global variable in Program.cs.